# How can I record video and clip into peace at the same time using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is my question, I need to implement a function that satisfy the following:

1. Record your computer monitor(or any other video) into video in any format
2. You have a button, every time you click the button, the process will ouput a 20 seconds clip with mp4 format.
   .e.g:
   I start a ffmpeg recording process at 00:00:00, and I click the button at 00:01:20, that will output a mp4 video from the Video recorded by step 1 from 60th second to 80th second
3. The mp4 produce by step 2 is allow some bias for seconds. Maybe from 61st second to 79th second in step 2
4. the clipping process is quick, need just few second

Is there any way to implement this function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my thinking

1. due to requirement 4, the clip process must using -c copy parameter
2. the last production is mp4, so the encoder is libx264
3. avi format can support record and clip at the same time, so i use avi as output format

And here is my solution:
I record the video using libx264 with avi format

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0 -c:v "libx264" output.avi
```

when i need to clip video, i will use command like

```
ffmpeg -i output.avi -ss 0 -t 20 -c copy output.mp4
```

This two command works perfectly, but only on local device.
If i upload the video to the internet, and play the video using browser, the frame will disorder